# I'm using Simple lightbox plugin, But i need zoom in/out option inside lightbox

Tags: wordpress, lightbox

I use simple lightbox plugin, I need zoom in/out button inside lightbox.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you provide more detail? what's the context?

Comment: I would suggest to look for alternatives, for example, http://fancyboxjs.com